# Enable JavaScript python request cloudflare (cfscrape or cloudscraper)

Tags: python

I'm collecting information from a site that is protected by CloudFlare, everything works fine, but the site itself has a check for JavaScript enabled.

There is practically no JavaScript on this site, all information is static, most likely it is protection from bots.

Is it possible to specify some kind of title, or something like that so that the site understands that I'm not a bot? That is, JavaScript is enabled.

Comment: even i am facing the same problem